# entity framework SaveChanges conflicting changes to the role of the relationship have been detected

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have this code:

```
public class Taxi
{
     [DataMember]
     public int Id { get; set; }         

     [DataMember]
     public string CarModel { get; set; }         

     [IgnoreDataMember]
     public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }       
}

public class Order
{
     [DataMember]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public string AddressFrom { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public int? TaxisId { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
     public virtual Taxi Taxi { get; set; }
}
```

............

```
public void SomeMethod(int orderId)
{
   using (var db = new MyDbContext())
   {
      var order = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==orderId);
      if (order!=null) //order.TaxisId = 1
      {
        order.TaxisId = null;
        db.SaveChanges(); //everything Ok! order.TaxisId becomes null
        if (SettingsModel.AutoSetToTheNextTaxi)
        {
          OrderSetTaxis(order.Id, 2, db); //trying to set order.TaxisId to another value.
        }
        ......
        //Some Code
        ......
      }
   }
}

public void OrderSetTaxis(int orderId, int taxiId, MyDbContext db)
{
  var order = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==orderId);
  if (order!=null)
  {
    order.TaxisId = taxiId;
    db.SaveChanges(); //this throw exception
  }
}
```

When i calling method I have this exception - "Conflicting changes to the role 'Order_Taxi_Target' of the relationship 'DispKernel.Entities.MyDbContext.Order_Taxi' have been detected."
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting the foreign key to null first then setting it to a new value, why don't you just set it to the new value? Why does it ever need to be null?

Comment: I have changed code a little. Calling OrderSetTaxis is optional.

Comment: If you saved changes for 'order.texiId = null' then why you passing dbcontext in the next go. Try creating new dbcontext in 'OrderSetTexis' method

Comment: After calling OrderSetTaxis I have some code that uses dbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that you have 2 conflicting changes to the same entity in the context at the same time, so it cannot track these changes. However there is no point in ever making both changes so simply do the following:

```
public void SomeMethod(int orderId)
{
   using (var db = new MyDbContext())
   {
      var order = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==orderId);
      if (order!=null) //order.TaxisId = 1
      {        
        if (SettingsModel.AutoSetToTheNextTaxi)
        {
          order.TaxisId = 2;
        }
        else
        {
          order.TaxisId = null;
        }
        db.SaveChanges(); 
      }
   }
}
```